# Create a flexbox with 3 items in it that are equal of width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a flexbox with 3 items in it that are equal of width. The problem is if I add padding or gap or both. It breaks (only 2 columns)! **I do not want to use grid. It needs to be flex!**

This is the Html and css

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.color {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.spacing {
    padding: 1em;
}
.flex-item {
    flex: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ...so why does your example have 8 items, not 3?

Comment: I like to add as many as I want but from the moment there are more than 3 on one line they should be of equal width.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following to `.flex-item`

```
flex: calc((100% - 2rem) / 3);
box-sizing: border-box;
```

**- 2rem** is becuase you have `gap` between first and second and second and third element.

Thus, your code should be as follows:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.color {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.spacing {
    padding: 1em;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: calc((100% - 2rem) / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">8</div>
</div>
```

And if you want that the last two divs take only first and second column use then `width` instead of `flex` in `.flex-item`.

```
.flex-item {
  width: calc((100% - 2rem) / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Thus something as follows:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.color {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.spacing {
    padding: 1em;
}
.flex-item {
  width: calc((100% - 2rem) / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item color spacing">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your calculation is a little off and is only corrected by `flex-grow` you need to subtract the gaps from the 100% before you divide it through 3. If you multiple your calculation with 3 you get a sum of `100% - 6rem`

Comment: @tacoshy You're right. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Change the `box-sizing` of the `flex-item` to include the paddings by using: `box-sizing: border-box`
2. Include the gap in the calculations. I recommend you to use a CSS-Variable for the gap: `calc((100% - (2 * var(--gap))) / 3)`

```css
:root { 
  --gap: 1rem;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.color {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.spacing {
  padding: 1em;
}

.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: calc((100% - (2 * var(--gap))) / 3);
}

.span-2 {
  flex: calc(((100% - (2 * var(--gap))) / 3) * 2 + var(--gap));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing span-2">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">6</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">7</div>
  <div class="flex-item color spacing">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Love this. How would you move forward, if the first row for example needed to have 1 item occupy 1/3 of the space and the 2 item 2/3 of the space. Again not using grid. I try to understand what the possibilities of flex are.

Comment: add an additional class for the element that should span 2 columns by using `flex: calc(((100% - (2 * var(--gap))) / 3) * 2)`

Comment: Genius!! I added it but I notice now that the gap does not correctly align with the gap on the line beneath because I have 3 items there. How can I solve that?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fogot to re-add 1 gap: `flex: calc(((100% - (2 * var(--gap))) / 3) * 2 + var(--gap))`

Comment: Yes!! works!! I added an extra class: flex: calc((100% - (5 * var(--gap))) / 6) - so the first line has now 2 items which each take 1/6 and than the 3th item takes up the rest of the space. I wonder now if it's possible to move the 3th item to the next line. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make the padding/margin in an element *inside* the `.flex-item`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.spacing {
  margin: 1em;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">1</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">2</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">2</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">4</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">5</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">6</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">7</div></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><div class="color spacing">8</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply forbid padding from adding to the total width by adding this css

```
.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: this fixes the paddings but not the gaps.

Comment: If you wish to add gaps you could account for them in the width dimensioning
gap: 10px
3 gaps
flex-item{
width: calc((100% / 3) - 3 * 10px)
}

Comment: that calculation is way off. The gap is 1rem. Then you have only 2 gaps in 3 columns. Last but not least you need to subtract the gaps from the 100% before you divide it by 3.